# Invalid date type error when saving date inline from ui grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

Getting error Invalid date type in magento2

my code is:

```
<column name="from_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
             <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                 <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item> 
            </item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Starting Date</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: which datatype you used for storing date?

Comment: timestamp @DharmendraJadav

Comment: Your code is working perfact in m225. I have checked. Not getting any kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <column name="from_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                            <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                            <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Starting Date</item>
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: Notworking
getting ajax response 
items[49905][from_date]: Invalid date
items[49905][to_date]: Invalid date

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, may be date formate not getting proper or data not getting proper from DB.